# High Charts - Gradients on both Vertical and horizontal

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm utilzing HighCharts to do some simple bar charts. The charts sometimes are horizontal bar graphs, and sometimes vertical bar graphs. Is there a way to modify the gradient order and shadow dependant on whether it's horizontal or vertical?

Here's the beginning of my setup in the js:

function buildChart(cType, cTitle, categoriesX, titleY, seriesData1, isPercent) {

```
var flipLabels = 0,
    labelSpace = 40,
    labelWidth = 160,
    labelHeight = 60,
    labelAlign = 'center',
    labelSize = 12,
    labelSpacingY = 30,
    labelSpacingX = 0,
    yAxisLineColor = null,
    yAxisTitle = '',
    chartWidth = 800, //$('#chart_modal').width(),
    chartHeight = (60 * categoriesX.length) + 150,
    perShapeGradient = {
        x1:0,
        y1:0,
        x2:1,
        y2:0
    },
    gradientBuild = [
        [0, '#6482fb'],
        [1, '#5775df']
    ];
```

Vertical charts look correct, light to dark, with the shadow on the right:
[image: Vertical charts look correct]

But Horziontal are backwards. Should be light on top. Dark on bottom with the shadow below:
[image: Horizontal bar charts are flipped]

How do I flip the gradient and the shadow, but only for the horizontal bar charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are talking about two different chart types.  What you are referring to as a ***horizontal bar chart*** is simply `type: 'bar'` in HighCharts.  A ***vertical bar chart*** is simply `type: 'column'` in HighCharts.  Here are samples on how to control the shading for each type:

- [HighCharts column type](http://jsfiddle.net/J3qN8/1/)
- [HighCharts bar type](http://jsfiddle.net/6VMsp/1/)

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to control the shadow offset width and color.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the shadow to set at all. My series is set via two variables: series:[
   {
    name:titleY,
    data:seriesData1
   }
  ]

When I add on shadow, nothing changes. Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: you have to have `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.js"></script>` included in your page